# Amazon Web Services: Delete item on DynamoDB Database from Lambda Function

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How can I delete an item from a DynamoDB database from a Lambda function. I know how to put and item. Here is working code:

```
dynamo.putItem({
            "TableName": "Table",
            "Item": item
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Failure: " + err);
                context.succeed("Failure!");
                context.done();
            } else {
                console.log("Success!");
                context.succeed("Success!");
                context.done();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

this works for me...  omitting the lambda boilerplate stuff...

```
    var tableName = "Users"
dynamodb.deleteItem({
    "TableName": tableName, 
    "Key" : {
        "UserId": event.UserId
    }
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        context.fail('FAIL:  Error deleting item from dynamodb - ' + err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("DEBUG:  deleteItem worked. ");
        context.succeed(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction to the code above, this is working :

```
var tableName = "Users";
dynamodb.deleteItem({
    "TableName": tableName, 
    "Key" : {
        "UserId": {
            "N" : event.userId.toString()
         }
    }
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        context.fail('FAIL:  Error deleting item from dynamodb - ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log("DEBUG:  deleteItem worked. ");
        context.succeed(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;
  deleteConnectionId(connectionId).then(() => {
    callback(null, { statusCode: 200 , message: 'userId deleted'});
  });
};


function deleteConnectionId(connectionId) {
  return ddb
    .delete({ TableName: 'your table name', 
        Key: {
            userId : connectionId.toString() // userId is my PK in this case
         }
    } )
    .promise();
}
```